# (UWP) Is it possible to reduce the width of a specific listview item in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a listview with items horizontally stacked tabs at the bottom of the window. Whenever my window is resized, no of items in the tabs should decrease to accommodate the window width. Let's say I have 10 tabs when my app is in full screen mode, when I minimize to half the full screen mode, I should have 5 tabs + 1 more tab (which upon clicked should display a pop up of the remaining 5 items). I'm able to accomplish this partially by toggling the visibility of items. But I just wanted to know if there is way to reduce the width of only one listview item to zero?

```
<Grid  Name="BottomPaneGrid" 
               BorderBrush="#f0f0f0" 
               Background="{x:Bind BottomPaneBackground}"
               BorderThickness="{x:Bind BottomPaneThickness}"
               CornerRadius="{x:Bind BottomPaneCornerRadius}"
               Margin="{x:Bind BottomPaneMargin}"   
               >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="88"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind test.ModuleTabs}"                 
                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind test.DefaultModuleEnabledTab,Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectionChanged="ListViewBottomPaneControl_SelectionChanged"
                  x:Name="ListViewBottomPaneControl"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection/>
            </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />                    
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="entity:Tabs">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="TabListingItem"
                                    Visibility="{x:Bind Visibility,Mode=OneWay}">
                            <Image Source="{x:Bind ImagePath,Mode=OneWay}" Opacity="0.8" 
                                           ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Tabs,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="11"
                                               Opacity="0.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    <!--</Grid>-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Background="Transparent" x:Name="MoreLink"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"               
                Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                Visibility="Collapsed" Flyout="{StaticResource MoreTabsStyle}">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"                                
                            Visibility="Visible">
                <Image Source="/Entities/Assets/morel-1.jpg" Opacity="0.8" 
                           ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom" 
                           ToolTipService.ToolTip="More" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                <TextBlock Text="More" FontSize="11"
                               Opacity="0.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        <Button>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What have you done? Please show your XAML code.

Comment: I've added the xaml code above.

Comment: All right. I'm not sure why you want to use ListView to show items as Tab. There's a ready-made [TabView XAML control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/tabview). Why not use it directly?

Comment: Oh okay I wasn’t aware of that .. let me try that... the tabs being shown is dynamic .. hence I thought listview is a wise option..